# Parsing URL in R to extract specific data

Tags: r, urlparse, url-parsing

I have a data file which has a URL column in it. It looks something like this
`"https://www.google.com/ | query_string=utm_source=abc&utm_medium=yts&utm_campaign=123campaign&utm_term=camp%123&utm_content=brand&gclid=abcdefg|user_agent=xyz"`

I want these data in seperate columns with their respective values as shown below

```
utm_source utm_medium utm_campaign utm_term utm_content user_agent
abc          yts      123campaign  camp%123   brand         xyz
```

Using dput for URL results in

```
c("https://www.google.com/ | query_string=null | ip_address=123.113.64.211 | user_agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36","https://www.google.com/ | query_string=gclid=Lxi6sNo-A17RohDAcQgvD_fw4 | ip_address=167.11.116.237 | user_agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-C701F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Mobile Safari/537.36","http://m.facebook.com/ | query_string=utm_source=fb&utm_medium=ctw&utm_campaign=abcPant_rem&utm_content=PantShirt | ip_address=106.193.181.252 | user_agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G975F Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/218.0.0.32.158;]")
```

Comment: are you sure the link you provided works?

Comment: No thats just a sample..but that's how the structure is

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the entries in `URL` contains multiple fields in the query string, and the first one doesn't contain any. You can't really make a data frame from the example in the question, but you can make a list of named vectors containing the fields in the query string like this:

```r
queries <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(URL, "query_string="), 
                           `[`, 2), " \\|"), `[`, 1)

lapply(strsplit(queries, "\\&|="), function(x) 
  setNames(x[seq(length(x)/2) * 2], x[seq(length(x)/2) * 2 - 1]))
#> [[1]]
#> null 
#>   NA 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                       gclid 
#> "Lxi6sNo-A17RohDAcQgvD_fw4" 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    utm_source    utm_medium  utm_campaign   utm_content 
#>          "fb"         "ctw" "abcPant_rem"   "PantShirt"
```

Comment: I used the first command which is fields=strsplit...but getting the below error                                                       In charToRaw(URL) : argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored

Comment: @anonymus that doesn't make any sense. Is `url` a character vector?

Comment: Its a column consisting of multiple URLs. I am still getting an error.So if my data is stored in Mydata and the URL column inside Mydata is MyURL then I have replaced your command as fields <- strsplit(URLdecode(URL =Mydata$MyURL), "&|=")[[1]][-1]

Comment: Any answer @Allan

Comment: @anonymous it seems as though URLdecode doesn't like vectorized input. Do you get a correct result with `Mydata$MyURL[1]`?

Comment: USed what you have mentioned but in the second seq code getting this error Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: not getting the solution using this..I am still stuck here

Comment: can you please help with this?

Comment: @anonymus Could you maybe edit your question to include the result of `dput(mydata)`? I'm sure I could get it to work if you did that.

Comment: @anonymus see my update. With the data you have, the fields in the query strings are all different. You can't make a useful data frame out of them.

Comment: @anonymus You must misunderstand me. I'm not saying that I can't find a solution, I'm saying that all your URLs have different fields, so it wouldn't make sense to put them in a data frame. In the first row for example, when the query string is `null`, what would you put in the columns `utm_medium`, `utm_source` etc? You _could_ put them in a dataframe by having all the fields from each url as column headers, but for the URL object in your question, this would be pointless. There _is_ no remaining problem - your data is what it is.

Comment: Understood @AllanCameron

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution using the URL provided.

```
url <- "https://www.google.com/ | query_string=utm_source=abc&utm_medium=yts&utm_campaign=123campaign&utm_term=camp%123&utm_content=brand&gclid=abcdefg|user_agent=xyz"
```

`str_match_all` extracts patterns.

- `\\w+`: Match one or more word characters
- `(...)`: Capture group
- `(?:...)?`: Match group zero or one times, but don't capture the group. This is used to handle the `query_string=` part of the URL.

```
stringr::str_match_all(url, "(?:\\w+=)?(\\w+)=(\\w+)")
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]                          [,2]           [,3]         
#> [1,] "query_string=utm_source=abc" "utm_source"   "abc"        
#> [2,] "utm_medium=yts"              "utm_medium"   "yts"        
#> [3,] "utm_campaign=123campaign"    "utm_campaign" "123campaign"
#> [4,] "utm_term=camp"               "utm_term"     "camp"       
#> [5,] "utm_content=brand"           "utm_content"  "brand"      
#> [6,] "gclid=abcdefg"               "gclid"        "abcdefg"    
#> [7,] "user_agent=xyz"              "user_agent"   "xyz"
```

`str_match_all` returns a list of matrices where the first column is the complete match followed by each of the captured groups. Keep only the captured groups.

```
stringr::str_match_all(url, "(?:\\w+=)?(\\w+)=(\\w+)")[[1]][,2:3]
#>      [,1]           [,2]         
#> [1,] "utm_source"   "abc"        
#> [2,] "utm_medium"   "yts"        
#> [3,] "utm_campaign" "123campaign"
#> [4,] "utm_term"     "camp"       
#> [5,] "utm_content"  "brand"      
#> [6,] "gclid"        "abcdefg"    
#> [7,] "user_agent"   "xyz"
```

Comment: I tried this but getting an error like as shown below:                           
Error in stri_match_all_regex(string, pattern, omit_no_match = TRUE, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)

Comment: The `url` variable needs to be a character vector. Look at the result of `class(url)`.

Comment: Checked the class..its a character

Comment: Used this but how to seperate in different columns?

Comment: class URL is a character. I am having a column consisting of similar URL's. For one URL, I am getting this solution but when I consider for all, I am unable to split